# Why does Eclipse refuse to run a Java class as AWS SAM Local instead of just Java?

Tags: eclipse, aws-sdk

I am using Eclipse for Java development.  All was working fine.  Installed the AWS_SDK because I need to use Glacier in something I am doing.  Did a "New" "AWS Java Project".  Created my first Java class and went to run it.  I only get the choices as running as a "AWS SAM Local" or to use a configuration which is also set to run the SAM Local.  I am not given the choice to just run it as Java. I also have an older Java project in the same workspace and I can run classes there as Java. I tried creating another AWS Java Project and class but the same problem persists.

Has anyone run into this and know how to fix it?